# Binomial coefficient in closed form problem

Tags: combinatorics

Is anybody to give a insight, please?

> $8.9$. Let $\ell$ be an even positive integer. Express $$\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^\ell(-1)^i\binom{n}k^2\binom{2k}i\binom{2n-2k}{\ell-i}$$ in closed form.

[source]
http://books.google.co.kr/books?id=60rb-NF-uvYC&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=solution,+8.9.+,in+closed+form.+Titu+Andreescu,&source=bl&ots=wvuG4kOIwp&sig=6xz4QbBut56E7Ko5XQVIsFg0ZQU&hl=ko&sa=X&ei=sAZzVImzPIO2mQXEt4HYBQ&ved=0CBkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=solution%2C%208.9.%20%2Cin%20closed%20form.%20Titu%20Andreescu%2C&f=false